# Is an RFP50N06 a valid replacement for an IRF50N06 MOSFET?

Tags: mosfet, amplifier, replacement

I recently blew a MOSFET in my car audio amplifier because some water got on it. The MOSFET used in the amplifier is an IRF50N06.  I was wondering if the RFP50N06 MOSFET would be a good replacement because it's easier for me to get one of those.

They both support 50 A and 60 V max. The Rds(ON) is slightly higher for the RFP50N06 (22 vs 15-17 mΩ).

The real concern for me is the Vgs(Vth) for the two. The IRF shows min/max of 1.2 and 2.5 V while the RFP shows min/max of 2 and 4 V. For the amplifier, will this be a significant issue because the gain depends on Vgs?

Here are the datasheets for both:

- [RFP50n06](https://www.mouser.com/datasheet/2/308/1/RFP50N06_D-1814731.pdf)
- [IRF50n06](https://alltransistors.com/adv/pdfdatasheet_china/irf50n06.pdf)

Comment: More concerned about the Qg(tot), which seems like a typo (10x too small) for the "IRF" part, considering the Ciss are much closer together. No characteristic curves doesn't help either. It's probably fine though; what have you got to loose, a dead amp and some time?

Comment: True.  I'll probably make the swap and see if everything works.  Thanks!

Comment: (@TimWilliams look at the differences in test conditions: IRF \$V_{DD}\$ 15 V, \$V_{GS}\$ 10 V vs. RFP 48 V & 20 V - @ 15/10, it probably is much closer at about 70 nC max.)

Comment: Do you know whether this is a switch-mode amplifier rather than a linear one?

Comment: @greybeard Oh that *is* bizarre, "Qg(tot)" is highly nonstandard at 20V. So it's more like a factor of 2-3 difference in charge or area. And the RFP doesn't give a Qg(Vgs) curve.

Comment: I replaced the MOSFET and it worked!  Thanks everyone for your help.